# HoloColorsGenerator and ActionBarSherlock crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

Here is what I did:

1. Create new Android project
2. Added ActionBarSherlock
3. Added Action Bar Color generator files
4. TESTED APPLICATION - Running on 2.x and 4.x with my action bar colors
5. Create files through holo color generator
6. Added holo color generator files to project
7. Did not change theme or anything. As of right now, the application should still run, as I didn't change any themes in the manifest or styles.
8. TESTED APPLICATION - Tried Running on 2.x and 4.x but crashes every time

I don't understand how the application can be crashing if I never set the new styles/theme.

I get the same crash on every device version.

Logcat:

```
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.whatthe/com.example.whatthe.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:134)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at com.example.whatthe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    ... 11 more
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    ... 24 more
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3340)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
07-23 23:32:31.942: E/AndroidRuntime(13026):    ... 27 more
```

**EDIT #1**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="CheckedTextView" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton1" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar2" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkedTextView1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

That stack trace indicates an error with your RelativeLayout, where a dimension is set that is not actually a dimension.

Comment: Posted my activity_main.xml in Edit #1.